# Retrieving speed record from a GPS nav sys

Tags: gps

Can I retrieve my speed record from the onboard GPS navigation system (or, alternatively, from an android phone) for the purposes such as disputing a traffic ticket?

Comment: What is the year/make/model of your vehicle. Also, Android phones don't save a full record of your instantaneous speed, only periodic locations (if enabled), which aren't accurate or consistent enough to dispute your ticket. (...unless you are using a third-party app which specifically captures and stores your speed.)

Comment: @the_storyteller, Honda Odyssey EXL 2013 w/Nav.

Comment: Even if the ability to do that was available, the police would just start asking questions about calibration, data integrity, etc.

Comment: @PeteCon, this is not how traffic court works in US: the cops don't ask questions, only the judge does. The defendant's job is to establish reasonable doubt; if the cops says "I looked at the radar and the speed was X", but unable to produce the radar reading, and the motorist says, "here's the printout from my GPS; at the time the ticket was written my speed was Y", and there is no evidence that GPS was wrong, that's more than enough for reasonable doubt.

Comment: @Michael reasonable doubt has to be reasonable, which means the evidence must be credible. If you have the NMEA raw logs, you may be able to provide an accurate level of resolution to prove your case, but you still don't have an established chain of custody for the logs, and that kind of data is very easily tampered with.